# Understanding memory allocation and data retrieval in GNU Assembly

Tags: assembly, endianness

```
.data
        x:      .int 1145258561
.bss
        .lcomm temp, 4
.text
        .globl _start
        _start:
                movl $4, %eax
                movl $1, %ebx
                movl x, %ecx
                movl $1, %edx
                int $0x80

                movl $1, %eax
                movl $0, %ebx
                int $0x80
```

I'm working on a little endian machine and trying to understand which memory byte of a 4 byte integer would be printed to the screen when I try to print it. The value of integer x, 1145258561, is a special value because it's hexadecimal translation is 0x44434241. This means the 4 consecutive bytes of this integer contain 0x44, 0x43, 0x42 and 0x41 respectively (Or simply ASCII Letter D, C, B and A respectively.

Since I'm operating on a little endian machine, as I mentioned earlier, these ASCII letters would be stored in reversed order. Lets say the memory address of integer x is 0x600000. So A, B, C, D should get stored on memory location 0x600000, 0x600001, 0x600002 and 0x600003.

Upon printing 1 byte (edx=1) it'd either take the first or the last byte of the integer so either A or D should be printed but surprisingly there's no output on the screen. So now I have 3 questions:

1. Why isn't there any output on the screen?
2. Which memory location, 0x600000 or 0x600003, would be chosen to print in such a case?
3. What should be the output if I try to print 4 bytes i.e. change edx to 4? (I tried doing it but there's still no output on the screen.)

Comment: It could be operating system specific. On Linux consider using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) & [gdb(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) on your program.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I'm using GDB and yet I couldn't find the reason for no output. All the values are allocated in memory as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: But did you try `strace` ? It might be very helpful. Also, I see no memory allocation in your code (the memory is used *statically*; dynamic allocation could use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I've never heard of it. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Isn't the `movl x, %ecx` loading content of memory, instead of loading the address into `ecx`? (I'm always very confused by AT&T syntax, but I think immediate should start with `$`). (the sys_write needs address of course, not content)

Comment: But loading a memory cell is not *allocating* memory

Comment: As @Ped7g hinted, you want `movl $x, %ecx` because the syscall needs the address not the value.

Comment: @Ped7g: `movl x, %ecx` loads the value of integer x into register ecx. Just the way you mentioned and that's exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: No that's not what you want to do, because the write syscall expects an address not a value.

Comment: That's nice you want it like that, but sys_write will refuse to cooperate, it wants address (pointer) of memory (i.e. that 0x600000), where it will find the data to be written into the file. If you give it the integer `0x44434241`, that's invalid address, and it will crash reading that memory, not outputting anything.

Comment: @Jester: Yes. I got the output now!! Thanks. Can you or Ped7g put it as an answer so I can accept it. It might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: And that's exactly what `strace` would have shown you if you had listened to Basile...  `write(1, 0x44434241, 1)  = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)`

Comment: "helpful to someone else" - I doubt it, there's for sure already similar question here on SO, and it's sort of trivial, calling system call with wrong arguments will produce wrong results, as the good old adage says: garbage in, garbage out. Once you will adjust your mental model a bit more toward ASM, losing the "variables" like "value of integer x", and switch to ASM way (value in memory at label x), it will come more naturally to you, what is what and why and how...

Comment: The Gnu assembler supports an Intel syntax mode; perhaps you'd find that less confusing and minimize the chances that you make annoying little typos like this? Ped7g and I certainly would! Just add the `.intel_syntax` directive to the top of your code file.